# Update Post Title when you create new Custom Post Type with ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have removed the default Title field from a specific Custom Post Type in Wordpress. But on the post table, it is shown as `(no title)`. Obviously :P

What I try to do is to use an ACF field as the title. At the moment, I do it like this

```
function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    global $_POST;

    $new_title = get_field('username', $post_id);
    $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );

    $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_title' => $new_title,
      'post_name' => $new_slug
    );

    // Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
  return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/update_value/name=username', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

The problem is that it only works when I update a custom post type and not when I create one. I wasn't able to find a proper filter on ACF documentation. Any idea?

Comment: why not use the `add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_update_value', 20);` action

Comment: like so : https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/createupdate-post-title-from-acf-fields/